# Windows Store App Submission Trailer Error

Tags: windows-store

I'm currently trying to create a Trailer for the app I'm going to submit to the MS Windows Store. I've created an MP4 of the app in action (using the Xbox Game Bar) but was unable to create it at the required resolution (i.e. 1920 x 1080 as stated in the MS documentation). So I used an online video converter to reformat the MP4 to the correct resolution. However, when I tried to upload the MP4 file I got the following error message:

"We couldn’t import "AppTrailerName".mp4. Please make sure it’s a valid trailer file and try again."

I thought this might be because of the online converter so I tried a different online converter but got exactly the same error message.

I read this link (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/762) from someone who, it seems, had the same problem but the solution (uploading the trailer to the Apple Store) is not viable for me.

What I can't understand is if MS validates the uploaded trailer and finds it in error, why can't MS tell me exactly what's wrong with it so I can fix it?

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I've done wrong and how I should create a successful trailer?

Kind regards,

RobDev

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about an app store procedure and not about programming.